# Wordpress . urls amigables con categoria

Tags: html, html5, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Buenas tengo instalado un blog con wordpress donde la estructura entre otras temáticas es esta

**Consolas**

- Mandos
- Cables
- Otros

Lo tengo todo como "entradas" asociado a una categoría que es "consolas"pero cuando me construye las url me lo hace en el formato

```
/consolas/
/mandos/
/cables
/otros/
```

A mi me gustaría que los "sub items" mandos , cables y otros las rutas fueran del tipo "/consolas/mandos" , .... pero el wordpress cuando lo edito me lo vuelve a poner por defecto.

Como puedo hacer esto?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar de manera permanente el cómo se configuran las urls en 'wordpress' debes ir en el menú principal a:

```
   AJUSTES - ENLACES PERMANENTES - ESTRUCTURA PERSONALIZADA
```

Seleccionar está opción por defecto. Sí lo quieres hacer desde la configuración del código debes ir al archivo '.htacces' y modificar las 'wp_options'.

Dejo un enlace a la documentación de wordpress donde explica con detalle como proceder respecto a tu pregunta: https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/

Comment: Muchas gracias lo solucioné. gracias